# In a Bugzilla extension, how does one detect a new comment being added?

Tags: perl, bugzilla

Which hook does one need to hook into to determine when a new comment is being added to a bug?

My use case is that whenever a comment is being added I need to process all comments, and perform some action based on that. However, this action is “expensive”, so I don't want to perform the action unless a comment has really been added.

The only way that I have found so far to determine this is to hook into `object_end_of_update` with the code:

```perl
sub object_end_of_update {
  my ($self, $args) = @_;

  my ($object, $old_object, $changes) = @$args{qw(object old_object changes)};
  print STDERR "--- Object Type: " . ref $object;
  if ($object->isa('Bugzilla::Bug')) {
    # Load comments on the old object here, otherwise by the time we get
    # to bug_end_of_update it is too late, and we cannot determine if a
    # new comment has been added or not.
    $old_object->comments({order=>'oldest_to_newest'});
  }
}
```

and then to hook into `bug_end_of_update`, whereupon I can do something like:

```perl
sub bug_end_of_update {
  my ($self, $args) = @_;

  my ($bug, $old_bug, $timestamp, $changes) = @$args{qw(bug old_bug timestamp changes)};
  # Note that this will only work if the old comments have already been
  # loaded in object_end_of_update, otherwise when we get the old comments
  # here, it just goes to the DB, and gets all of the comments, including
  # the new one, if there is one.
  my $oldComments = $old_bug->comments({order=>'oldest_to_newest'});
  my $newComments = $bug->comments({order=>'oldest_to_newest'});
  if (scalar(@$newComments) > scalar(@$oldComments)) {
    # If we added a new comment, then perform processing.
    do_slow_action($bug);
  }
}
```

However, this feels fragile, and even if it isn't, is definitely not clear code.

What is the correct way to determine that a comment has been added to a bugzilla bug?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a hook to the Bugzilla source code.
You could add a database trigger that is fired whenever an update occurred on the field comments.

The advantage is that as long as the database schema doesn't change too much with newer versions, the trigger will keep working. (more information: [Database triggers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger)).

Here is an example:

```
use bugs;

create TRIGGER new_comment 
AFTER UPDATE ON bugs_fulltext 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

IF NEW.comments <> OLD.comments 
THEN 

.... //execute your script

END IF 
END;
```

Comment: While I know it is possible to call web services from the database, this would end up spreading the logic in more places than I would like.